# Run the Powershell script to automatically refresh Excel file with no Excel Application

Tags: powershell

I am running this PowerShell script to automatically refresh data in Excel file. I got to know that since Excel is not installed in that VDI machine I cannot run the following code. What should I do to "automatically refresh Excel file once a day". Excel file contains just one sheet.
I do not use Powershell at all in my work but I got this request.
The Powershell version is : 5.1.14409.1027
VDI is using Windows Server 2012 R2 and version is 6.3

```
$file = 'E:\Excel\filename.xlsx'
$x1 = New-Object -ComObject "Excel.Application"
$x1.Visible = $false
$enddate = (Get-Date).tostring("dd-MM-yy")
$filename = 'E:\Excel\filename.xlsx ' + $enddate + '.xlsx'
$wb = $x1.workbooks.Open($file)
$wb.RefreshAll()
$wb.SaveAs($filename)
$wb.Close()
$x1.Quit()
Remove-Variable wb,x1
```

Comment: [What did you search for](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=%27powersehll+excel+module%27&t=h_&ia=web)? You cannot take action on an Excel file unless Excel is active, using COM as you are. You need to code this completely on your own or use a 3rdP tool/module, which takes you back to 'X' or 'Y' may not be used/possible install systems. [See also](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=powersehll+%27automate+Microsoft+Excel+without+Microsoft+Excel%27&t=h_&ia=web)

Comment: Did you think of copying the file to your computer where Excel is installed, update it there and finally copy the updated file back to the server?

Comment: @Theo We are not allowed to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way to go would be to not use Excel COM object. But you would need to define what refresh means in Excel. So let's say you run a SQL query and return the result in a spreadsheet. You could write:

```
Install-Module ImportExcel -Scope CurrentUser # only once
Install-Module dbatools -Scope CurrentUser # only once

# every day
$sql = 'SQL1'
$file = 'E:\Excel\filename.xlsx'
$query = "select name from master.sys.databases"
$result = Invoke-DbaQuery -SqlInstance $sql -Query $query
$result | Export-Excel -Path $file -WorksheetName Abc -TableName Abc
```